# Why does iPhone auto-correct suggest "되요" when I type "돼요"

Tags: grammar

My phone kept correcting "돼요" to "되요" (even though I kept manually choosing "돼요"), and for a brief period, convinced me "되요" was more correct...

But isn't 돼요 the more correct conjugation of 되다? Is 되요 also correct?

**Why does my phone keep telling me 되요 is better than 돼요?**

A quick check on Google translate and Papago returns similar translations for both forms.

Comment: 돼요 is the correct form. But then it should work even though you manually type 돼요, just choose it.

Answer (score 3):

The answers provided by other users in regards to grammar are correct. 돼요 is the correct usage. 되요 seems to be taking the dictionary form of 되다 and mashing it with the 요 formal ending.

To answer your question about why the iPhone corrects that, my comment is that the auto-correct with many keyboards that support Korean are sub-par. I have also tried Fleksy and it's Korean auto-correction is better but still not good. I used to use Korean with auto-correct on SwiftKey when I used Android but Korean support on iOS is not present.

Through my personal observation, none of the Koreans I have met has auto-correct turned on. I have received suggestions from Koreans to turn it off, because I was learning the wrong words. I personally use SwiftKey for English with auto-correct on and iOS Korean keyboard with auto-correct off.

Answer (score 1):

돼요 is not the "more" correct conjugation of 되다. It is nothing but a contraction of 되어.

So in your question, the verb 돼요 is correct. But if you are writing a different expression - say, 될 수 있다 - then 되 is correct.

I ran the following sentence in Google translate, and this is what I got:

> I became a pig.
>   나는 돼지가 되었다.

Notice that, while Google uses the 되 form, you can actually contract 되었다 to 됐다. The latter is preferred.

My guess is that Google decided to leave out unnecessary contractions to lessen the complexity of the algorithm behind the translator. It would be great if someone who knows the *real* reason can shed light on the topic.

Likewise. If we were to "expand" 돼요, we'd have to write 되어요, not 되요. If this is precisely what your phone is doing (돼요 -> 되요, verbatim), then I'm not really sure why.

Comment: That's a good point: I forgot "돼요" is actually a contraction; I just never type "되어요" or even "say" it that way in my head when talking. BTW my phone autocorrects 돼요 -> 되요, verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

One way to gage what to use is that replace 되 to 하 and 돼 to 해.

그렇게 됩니다. → 그렇게 합니다.(Correct)
그렇게 됍니다. →  그렇게 햅니다.(Incorrect)

그렇게 됬습니다. → 그렇게 핬습니다.(Incorrect)
그렇게 됐습니다. → 그렇게 했습니다.(Correct)

그렇게 될 수 있지. →  그렇게 할 수 있지.(Correct)
그렇게 됄 수 있지. →  그렇게 핼 수 있지.(Incorrect)

됬습니다. → 핬습니다.(Incorrect)
됐습니다. → 했습니다.(Correct)

됬거든요! → 핬거든요!(Incorrect)
됐거든요! → 했거든요!(Correct)

그래도 되요? → 그래도 하요?(Incorrect)
그래도 돼요? → 그래도 해요?(Correct)

The best way is not using iPhone auto correct. It's really lousy. I always turn off the function.